# Keycloak onLoad : 'check-sso' return error=login_required in url

Tags: keycloak

I'm working to have a login with **keycloak / keycloak-js** and the goal is to verify if the user already have a connection to keycloak or no. For that I use `onLoad: check-sso` during the keycloak.init.

When I have a user and click on the "impersonate", it work fine, but, if the user is not connected, if get a one second error in the url :

`http://localhost:8000/#error=login_required&state=...` 
I tried to changed the prompt='none' but it doesn't do nothing

I can't find any way to put a Silent mode to not show error if not logged in in the url bar ?

The project use Keycloak-js and is in Keycloak Server Version is 15.0.2

Still not working

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when using

**keycloak:** 18.0.1

**react-keycloak/web:** 3.4.0.

This was because i tried to use keycloak.init and passing the init option i wanted

```
keycloak.init({
   onLoad: "check-sso",
   silentCheckSsoRedirectUri: window.location.origin + "/silent-check-sso.html",
 })
```

As stated in the keycloak JS client doc.

But this caused a race conditionand kept on relaoding the page.

The fix was to pass the init options directly to the ReactKeyCloakProvider

```
<ReactKeycloakProvider
    authClient={keycloak}
    initOptions={{
      onLoad: "check-sso",
      silentCheckSsoRedirectUri:
        window.location.origin + "/silent-check-sso.html",
    }}
    onEvent={eventLogger}
    onTokens={tokenLogger}
  >
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </ReactKeycloakProvider>
```

This was not clarely stated in either the examples or the documentation.

Comment: Would be interesting to know what difference this makes e.g. for request params that keycloak receives